# Disable Owin Starup from code for some Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am using Owin and Unity and on every request the startup config is being called and working as expected but if their is some database connection issue or some other exception I am handling that exception in Global.asax and redirecting to another controller but for now the problem is as the exception is in startup.cs while I a redirecting to my Error controller the startup is again getting called and I am getting the same exception again making a redirect loop. Is their any way to disable owin startup for one controller or something lie that.

Some Code

```
var uow = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
var cc = (ClaimCache)container.Resolve<IClaimCache>();

var cts = new HaiClaimsTransformationService(uow,cc);
var ctos = new HaiClaimsTransformationOptions(cts);
app.UseClaimsTransformation(ctos);
```

Comment: can you please share the exception?

Comment: @Chandru The error is coming from Application core while I am trying to connect to Database, which is called on each startup.....

Comment: can you try to move the DB connection from OWIN Startup to Application_Start() - Global.asax?

Comment: Just add a return statement first line of public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)

Comment: @frenchie but I need it only for one controller, If I will add the return the it will be disabled for every controller

Comment: @Chandru check the updated question, the error is from the last line of code and I can't move that to Global.asax

Comment: Why do you use Global.asax when running Owin startup? the fill the same purpose. You could put all logic in Owin and delete the Global.asax file

Comment: @MarcusH I am using Global.asax only for Application_Error not for anything else.....

Comment: can you please share the Application_Error() code too?

Comment: Ok, could you update the question and add the exception msg aswell

Comment: @Chandru Response.Redirect("Another Controller");

Comment: @MarcusH ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor, Normal connection error

Comment: Try by adding this line Response.End(); in Application_Error();

Comment: @Chandru actually issue is I need to redirect to error controller and again the startup is being called and throwing the exception..

Comment: Basically Startup will be called once, I'm not sure how it's getting called multiple times for each pageload... Remove the Application_Error() method and use custom error...have a look into it http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages